# How do you prevent tmux from echoing the results of a command in the status bar?

Tags: tmux

Whenever I execute a command in tmux, for example, `set status`, the status bar turns yellow and echoes back the results of the command.  I find this behavior rather obtrusive.  Can I turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `quiet` server option to suppress many of the messages that are displayed in the status line (including the message shown by `set-option`). This will not suppress messages that come from using the `display-message` command.

If the `quiet` option is too broad<sup>*</sup>, or you want to be able to review the messages with `show-messages`<sup>†</sup>, then you might try setting the `display-time` session option to a very small value<sup>‡</sup>. This will affect *all* messages (even those from `display-message`), so it also may not be appropriate for all situations.

If you are only interested in suppressing the message from that one `set status` command/binding, and you are comfortable building software from source, then you might want to try out the current SVN trunk. Its `set-option` command has a `-q` option that suppresses the normal informational message (i.e. `set -q status`). This will be included in the next release (i.e. 1.7).

<sup>*</sup>`quiet` is is a server option, so it will affect all your sessions.
<sup>†</sup>`quiet` prevents the message from being entered into the `show-message` message log. By default, <kbd>(prefix)</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> is bound to `show-messages`.
<sup>‡</sup>`display-time` must be from the range 1–750. So zero is not a valid value, but the minimum value (1 millisecond) will probably be too fast to notice in most circumstances (e.g. unless your *tmux* server is on the other side of a slow link).